# How to replace the first line of every files found using "find"

Tags: linux

I have the list of files to replace the first line from running this command

```
find . -type f -name ".txt"
```

I want to replace the first line of the files found with this text "line 1"

Doing my research I found a way to delete the first line with

```
ex -sc '1d|x' file.txt
```

then prepend a file with

```
echo "line 1"|cat - file.txt > out && mv out file.txt
```

but I don't know how to delete first line and prepend for every files found

Comment: have you tried using the exec command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `exec`

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i .ORI '1s/.*/line 1/' {} \;
```

to edit the files in place saving backups as `.ORI`.

Comment: it has an error |     
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'

Comment: Try removing the space before `.ORI` or just removing this parameter (but then you won't have backups). There are many `sed` dialects with various idiosyncrasies.  If you need the script to be portable to various platforms, maybe switch to Awk or Perl which are better standardized.

Comment: I suppose this could be changed to work with `ex` instead of `sed` but you know, there's a reason we use `sed` for batch/programmed editing.

Comment: find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i.ORI '1 s/.*/line 1/' {} \;  note the changes in -i.ORI

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec or xargs with find, but for more complicated commands I always run processing in a loop. It's clearer that way. Here's what you can do:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | while read -r f; do
  ex -sc '1d|x' "$f"
  echo "line 1"|cat - "$f" > out && mv out "$f"
done
```

Comment: You should use `read -r` to avoid some pesky legacy behavior, and quote `"$f"` everywhere.

Comment: Prepending `.tmp` to full path names is not going to work very well anyway.

Comment: Good call quoting the filename. Reverted to the 'out' tempfile name.